# Getting generic type class using reflection

Tags: java, generics, reflection, deserialization

How do you get the class name of the generic type of `Collection`, using reflection, in this situation?

```
public class MyClass<T> implements TheirClass<Collection<T>> {
    ...

    public Class<?> getCollectionType() {
        //Need to use reflection on `this` in order to return the proper class
        //of the type of Collection 
    }
}
```

When we assign MyClass to be of type Collection, below:

```
MyClass<Collection<AnotherClass>> me = new MyClass<>();
```

The result would look like this below:

```
MyClass<Collection<AnotherClass>> meAnotherClass = new MyClass<>();
MyClass<Collection<String>> meString = new MyClass<>();

System.out.println(""+meString.getCollectionType().getClass() == String.class); //true
System.out.println(""+meAnotherClass.getCollectionType().getClass() == AnotherClass.class); //true
```

Comment: Your `MyClass` is not generic, but you are using it as if it was. Please clarify.

Comment: Good, thanks. The duplicate will have your answer.